# Java, Selenium: Verify URLs using HTTP Get - How long should it take

Tags: java, selenium, http

I have a test suite made up of 10 testcases. Each test case navigates to a section of the website and checks all the url's in that section. Each section has roughly 10 webpages and each webpage has over 100 href elements.

The total execution time is between 50 mins and 1 hour. How long should this take? 1 hr seems a bit excessive.

Helper method:

```
public Map<Boolean, List<String>> getHrefResponseBoolean() {
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href]"))
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> !s.getAttribute("href").endsWith("svg") && !s.getAttribute("href").endsWith("webmanifest") && !s.getAttribute("href").endsWith("ico?v=2"))
            .map(ele -> ele.getAttribute("href"))
            .map(String::trim)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(link -> 

HttpUtility.getResponseCode(link) == 200))

;
```

HttpUtility:

```
   /**
 * Hits the given url and returns the HTTP response code
 * @param link
 * @return
 */
public static int getResponseCode(String link) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    Integer responsecode = 0;
    try {
        url = new URL(link);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        responsecode = con.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // skip
    } finally {
        if (null != con)
            con.disconnect();
    }
    return responsecode;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to find which code is the bottleneck? response or helper?, maybe generating hardcoded response codes and check execution time. Also, consider using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for benchmarking tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shoul set timeout to connection. This is going to avoid con stuck.

```
public static int getResponseCode(String link) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    Integer responsecode = 0;
    try {
        url = new URL(link);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(1000); //set time out 
        responsecode = con.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // skip
    } finally {
        if (null != con)
            con.disconnect();
    }
    return responsecode;
}
```

Now, i beleave you should filter the WebElements through the xpath. I know it looks messy, but that's for xpath compatibility with version 1.

```
public Map<Boolean, List<String>> getHrefResponseBoolean() {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[not('svg' = substring(@href,string-length(@href) -string-length('svg') +1)) " + 
                "    and" + 
                "    not('webmanifest' = substring(@href,string-length(@href) -string-length('webmanifest') +1))" + 
                "    and" + 
                "    not('ico?v=2' = substring(@href,string-length(@href) -string-length('ico?v=2') +1))" + 
                "]"))
                .stream()
                .map(ele -> ele.getAttribute("href").trim())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(link -> getResponseCode(link) == 200));

  }
```

and then simply we could access the map to list all the bad urls as shown here.

```
map.get(true) // will contain all the good urls
map.get(false) // will contain all the bad urls
```